# Replace content from a Span by "..." after 70% of parent's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**UPDATE: ACTUAL PROBLEM**: Why does "(ciclo)" go to a line a bit lower than the rest? : http://jsfiddle.net/MV8q5/2/

---

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vAhCS/

I have this structure:

```
<div>
<span class="limitCharacters">CONTENT TO LIMIT</span><span>(ciclo)</span>
</div>
```

What I want is that, if `limitCharacters` span content occupies more than 70% of it's parent's div width, jQuery must remove the rest of the span replacing it by a "...". So that it shows in a single line the remained content of the span, plus the "...", plus  another inline span that goes right after this `limitCharacters` class Span (in the above code, "(ciclo)").

I solved this calculating limitCharacters' % width based on it's parent (calculates it correctly), and in case this result is 70 or more, it adjust span's width to 60%. The problem is that I must avoid any line break, and this can only be done by the `white-space: nowrap` css method, with the result that the 60% does not apply.

What I actually need is this:

[image: I need this]

What I actually have is this (see jsfiddle):

[image: oh]

If I avoid using nowrap method, it breaks line.

If I use overflow:hidden, it takes out the "..." and puts the second  ("ciclo") in a lower line height for some reaon I do not know (see example): http://jsfiddle.net/vAhCS/

[image: overflow hidden]

Comment: Overflow:hidden will remove the text behind "(Ciclo)"

Comment: It removes the "..." and sets (ciclo) in another height. I've updated question with this.

Comment: So, you want the overall effect to be something like this? (CSS-only): http://jsfiddle.net/vAhCS/3/

Comment: Yes Matt, but why does (ciclo) go lower line than the rest?

Comment: The way you are doing it, you will face more problems as you go further ahead... Like you would want your words to get hidden fully or shown fully... It may appear like this- Fotografia Digital y Tra... and you would want it to show Fotografia Digital y...So to get better control, I would recommend removing words from the end of the sentence and measuring the width again. If still big, remove one more word...and so on

Comment: Give a line-height to the limitCharacters span to bring ciclo up

Comment: @Biomehanika It doesn't, for me. Perhaps you're seeing something browser-specific?

Answer (score 1):

So you can use some css

```
.limitCharacters {
  width: 70%;   // Or you can put some fixed pixel value for 70%
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

I'm not sure how well a span would work, but a div would work well. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MV8q5/

**Updated answer:**

For the updated part of your question. 
It's because "ciclo" is out of the div and in a span. If you want it in the same line, put the

```
<span>(ciclo)</span>
```

into the div tag like: http://jsfiddle.net/MV8q5/3/

If you want it in a new line, put it in a new div like: http://jsfiddle.net/MV8q5/4/

Comment: Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/MV8q5/1/ I need (ciclo) to be after the span. In your example, (ciclo) goes a bit down than the rest of the text. If it wouldnt do this, it would be great. Why does this?

Comment: Please see updated info on the beginning of my question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Josua. I'll solve this by other ways, as it seems not possible to do it as I would have liked to. Maybe positioning the '(ciclo)' span on the beginning of the line..

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` [c.f css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: Please see updated info on the beginning of my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do this with jQuery. (Shock?). Pure CSS will be sufficient.

Take a look at this example. I have added background colors to make this really obvious as to what elements are which.

### Live Demo Example

http://jsfiddle.net/vAhCS/2/

### CSS

```
.tableContent {
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
}

.contentColumn40{
    height: 36px;
    width: 70%;

    border:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
}

.limitCharacters {
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;                   
    overflow: hidden;  
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;
}
```

[image]

Comment: EDIT_ sorry I post the wrong jsfiddle link. I need it to be on the same line, as the image attached before. How could I make this? It always breaks (ciclo)

Comment: Here you have the example: it does not matter how much space is left, (ciclo) never goes up to the same line http://jsfiddle.net/vAhCS/4/